# ¿Como instalar Entity Framework en visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Necesito ayuda en como instalar Entity Framework.

Cuando hago clic en "*Administrar paquetes NuGet*", en el listado no me sale el paquete EntityFramework. ¿Existe otro medio para hacerlo?

Comment: Asegurate en la ventana de "administrar paquetes nuget para la solucion" que vas a la pestaña "examinar" y que en Origen del paquete tengas "nuget.org"

Comment: @Pikoh Eso lo hice ya,pero me pone error cuando hago la búsqueda.

Comment: @Pikoh Acaso existe otro método para instalarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizar la instalación directamente desde la **Consola de administración de paquetes NeGet**. En el menú de opciones de Visual Studio accede a *Herramientas > Administrador de paquetes NuGet > Consola del Administrador de paquetes*, y escribe el siguiente comando:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Si quieres instalar una versión en concreto, puedes indicarlo también:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0
```

Para más información, puedes acceder a la página oficial de EntityFramework en **nuget.org**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

---

**UPDATE**: En caso de no funcionar todo lo anterior, puedes descargar el paquete .nupkg, e instalarlo desde la Consola de administración de paquetes NuGet indicando el **Path** donde se encuentra:

```
PM> Install-Package entityframework.6.3.0.nupkg -Source C:\PathDelArchivo\
```

O también:

```
PM> Install-Package C:\PathDelArchivo\entityframework.6.3.0.nupkg
```

Comment: Me lanza un error con la primera opcion:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Install-Package : No se puede encontrar el paquete 'EntityFramework' en origen''.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorI:NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManage

Comment: Acaso existe otro método para instalarlo?

Comment: @luis; Mírate el enlace que está en la pregunta, ahí podrás ver otras formas de instalarlo. Otra cosa, has comprobado si tienes acceso a Internet desde Visual Studio?

Comment: Acabo de descargar un paquete desde la pagina,específicamente la versión "entityframework.6.3.0.nupkg".Ahora bien,Cómo lo instalo?

Comment: @luis; Mírate la respuesta, la he editado.

Comment: @luis: Viste lo **nuevo** que te indiqué en la respuesta?. Te funcionó?.

Comment: @Gracias,pero solo busqué la carpeta donde se había descargado el paquete que descargué y lo instalé por la opción que aparece en lo de administrar paquetes.