# Problema Paquetes NuGet Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, packages, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Últimamente, para la Universidad hemos comenzado un proyecto aplicando **C#** en el entorno **Visual Studio 2019**. Estamos trabajando sobre **GitHub**, sincronizando los proyectos.

En este punto, ha sido necesario que un miembro del grupo añada el paquete `NuGet` `EntityFramework`. A algunas personas, al extraer y sincronizar el proyecto, esto no les ha causado problemas; sin embargo, a mí sí. El paquete en cuestión me dice que: **"No está disponible en este origen"**, y cuando intento restaurarlo, me aparece que no está el paquete en el directorio. Esto, concretamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He intentado hacer de todo. Usar la consola para instalar el paquete, cambiar la configuración de los `NuGet`... Y nada. Sería de gran ayuda cualquier aporte. Es para un proyecto, como he dicho y no puedo hacer nada si me salta ese fallo.

Gracias de antemano.

**EDITO:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITO2:**

Al descargarme el paquete y usar la consola, el error que aparece es este:

> Install-Package : Faltan algunos paquetes NuGet en la solución. Los paquetes se tienen que restaurar para crear el gráfico de 
>   dependencias. Restaure los paquetes antes de realizar cualquier operación.
>   En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
>   + Install-Package C:\Users\F541U\Downloads\entityframework.6.2.0.nupkg
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDITO FINAL:**

Al final he logrado solucionarlo. Independientemente de que el proyecto sea compartido, lo que debes hacer es eliminar de las referencias de tu proyecto aquellos 'elementos' que hagan mención al paquete NuGet que esté dando problemas.

Acto seguido, descargar desde **nuget.org** el paquete que queremos instalar en la extensión **.nupkg**. Desde la **Consola de Administrador de Paquetes**, usar el comando:

> Install-Package entityframework.6.2.0.nupkg -Source C:\PathDelArchivo\

(solución proporcionada por @RafaelAcosta), eligiendo el paquete que quieras en cuestión y el directorio.

Una vez hecho esto, ya me dejaba instalar el paquete, y no ha habido problemas a la hora de seguir trabajando en grupo para ningún miembro del equipo.

Comment: Hola. Esta misma pregunta ya ha sido planteada hoy mismo. Mírate este enlace [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315321/como-instalar-entity-framework-en-visual-studio-2019/315400?noredirect=1#comment572244_315400](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315321/como-instalar-entity-framework-en-visual-studio-2019/315400?noredirect=1#comment572244_315400)

Comment: Cambia el origen del Paquete en el combobox Debajo del texto "Administrar paquetes para la solución" si te funciona avisas. Es necesario tener internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como dice @jtaborga en los comentarios, cambia en el select **Origen del paquete:** de [**Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages**] a  [**nuget.org**].

---

**UPDATE:** en caso de seguir sin funcionar, mírate esta pregunta relacionada: [¿Como instalar Entity Framework en visual studio 2019?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315321/como-instalar-entity-framework-en-visual-studio-2019/315400?noredirect=1#comment572244_315400)

---

**UPDATE 2:** Si aun sigue sin funcionar, dentro del menú contextual **Orígenes de paquetes disponibles:**, cambia el Origen **https://www.nuget.org** por **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**. Así es como viene configurado en los proyectos por defecto.

Comment: Lo he intentado. Adjunto fotos con lo que he hecho (edito mensaje). Sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: que error de salida te marca, has un ping a nuget.org revisa que no este bloqueada la direccion por parte de tu red.

Comment: @ÁngelBaeza: Vete a la pestaña (tab) **Examinar**, y repite la acción de buscar el paquete.

Comment: @ÁngelBaeza: Mírate de nuevo la respuesta, la he editado.

Comment: Lo siento, pero estoy probando todo lo que me comentas y no funciona. Me da el mismo error siempre que hay en la última imagen subida.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Vale, he probado lo de hacer ping, y de hecho, se pierden los paquetes al conectar a la web nuget.org y demás. Alguna forma de desbloquear la dirección?

Comment: Me late que tienes que hablar al departamento de redes y darles la url nuget.org para que la desbloqueen del firewall

Comment: Si has probado todo lo que te he indicado y no te funciona, lo que dice @fredyfx es la última solución. Aun así, no se por que razón el firewall de tu red está bloqueando a nuget.org. Por favor, cuando lo compruebes, deja un comentario.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta ya enconrté la solución. He editado con lo nuevo. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo , cambiando la url del origen me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

- Primero me fije si también tenia añadido el ORIGEN DEL PAQUETE de "nuget.org" (en mi caso no tenia y lo añadí)
- Después me fuí a:

  - "herramientas" ->"administrador paquetes NUGET" -> "administrar paquetes NUGET para la solucion ..."
    y cambie el origen del paquete (porque el mio estaba apuntando a uno local).
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]